# WindowsForm DataGridView Overlapping WPF Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, datagridview

I'm using a WindowsForm Control i.e a DataGridView in a WPF application using the WinFormHost. The issue now is, the DataGridView is inside a WPF Scrollviewer control, so whenever i've datas in the DataGridView and its height increases automatically, it always overlaps all the WPF controls when ever i scroll or it's too long. Please what can i do, I've also tried ZIndex but not working. As shown in the image below

[image: Without Overlap]

[image: Overlapping]

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known issue in `WPF` when hosting non-`WPF` visual components. This is caused by the hosted component receiving a dedicated window handle which renders separately from the `WPF` visual tree.

Here are a few option for fixing your problem:

1. **Move to WPF's Data Grid** If there is now special reason for using `WinForm`'s data grid control, just move to `WPF`'s one, it will solve all your issues.
2. **Possible Workaround/Hack** It might be possible to create a transparent area in the `WPF` form and manipulate the `WinForms` grid when the user interacts with the scrollbars (or any other related component on the `WPF` form). It's ugly and complex, but it might work.
3. **Use WinForms' Data Grid Scrollbars** instead of relying on `WPF`'s scrollbar, just let the user interact with the ones on the `WinForms` data grid.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment, but i've tried all that. The reason i'm using WinForm DataGridView is because i can write code that Prints All values in the DataGrid, and Export To Excel. But if you have a way i can do all that with a WPF DataGrid, Please Kindly put me through it, thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use a `class` that represents a row and then fill an `ObservableCollection` with instances of that class and bind it to the `DataGrid`. Regarding the export to `Excel`, if you are using a `csv` file then it's just concatenating the values of each instance of the `class` and writing them to a file, but, if you need an `xlsx` file, than you'll need to use one of the `office` APIs to export the `class` instances to `Excel`.

Comment: I can use WPF DataGrid, but the API you talking about, i don't know about that API stuff. If you can help me out, i'll appreciate that... Thanks...

Comment: You can check the following link for working with office products programmatically: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx